Inconsistent result when finding the minimum speed to reach the highest point of a circular road
A car moves from $A$ to reach the highest point $B$ of a vertical circular road. Find the minum speed of the car at $A$. Ignore all frictions.

Using conservation of energy
\begin{align*}
mgh_A+\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2_A &= mgh_B+\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2_B\\
v^2_A &= 2g(h_B-h_A)+v^2_B\\
\end{align*}
The minimum of  $v_A$ makes $v_B=0$.
\begin{align*}
v_A &= \sqrt{2g\times 2R}\\
 &= 2\sqrt{gR}
\end{align*}
Using circular motion
Equating the weight and centripetal force, we get
$v_A=\sqrt{gR}$
I am confused with this result.


The minimum of $v_A$ makes $v_B=0$

The problem is that a car can't reach B and have zero velocity.   If it has some tangential velocity, then it can't get rid of it at B since the only forces on it at that point are vertical.   And if it doesn't have any tangential velocity then it can't get to B at all.   So the constraint is not valid.
